# Como obtener el modelo de un UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitableviewcontroller

Quisiera saber si alguien tiene una forma para obtener el valor de una clase `UITableViewCell`.

```
class EncuestaRespuestaC: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart01: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart02: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart03: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart04: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart05: UIButton!
    private var starts : [UIButton]!
    public var position = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        initView()
    }

    private func initView() {
        starts = [ivStart01, ivStart02, ivStart03, ivStart04, ivStart05]
        for start in starts {
            start.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }

    @objc private func onClick( _ button: UIButton) {
        position = button.tag
        setStart(position: position)
        position += 1
    }

    private func setStart(position: Int) {
        for (index, start) in starts.enumerated() {
            let color = index <= position ? Colors.Color.PURPLE_BUTTON : Colors.Color.GRIS_BUTTON
            setColorFilter(button: start, imageName: "ic_star", color: color)
        }
    }
}
```

//**Obs** cada una de mis 5 botones tiene un tag(1,2,3,4,5)

quiero notificar a mis modelos

**mi controllador**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let pregunta = preguntas[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ID_CELL, for: indexPath) as! EncuestaRespuestaC
        cell.lblDescription.text = pregunta.nomPregunta
        pregunta.respuesta = cell.position

        AnimationsUtil.animationTableCell(cell: cell)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }
```

**mi modelo es**

```
class EncuestaRespuestaBE: NSObject {
    internal var idPregunta: Int? = 0 {
        didSet { idPregunta = idPregunta ?? 0 }
    }

    internal var nomPregunta: String? = "" {
        didSet { nomPregunta = nomPregunta ?? "" }
    }

    internal var respuesta: Int? = 0 {
        didSet { respuesta = respuesta ?? 0 }
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "\(EncuestaRespuestaBE.self){ idPregunta: \(idPregunta!), nomPregunta: \(nomPregunta!), respuesta: \(respuesta!) }"
    }
}
```

Mi intención es notificar al model dentro del cell, y cuando llame a la lista de encuestas. Debería obtenerlos con los cambios de los botones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy segura de lo que pides. Lo que entiendo es que al pulsar uno de los botones en una celda acceda al objeto que le corresponde y guarde el botón pulsado.
Siguiendo la forma en la que yo lo hago cambiaría algunas cosas

Cambiaría la función cellForRowAt del controlador para que el setStart tenga lugar al cargar cada celda (de lo contrario se puede tener problemas debido a la reutilización de celdas) y pasaría aquí la función onClick de los botones para acceder al indexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let pregunta = preguntas[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ID_CELL, for: indexPath) as! EncuestaRespuestaC
    cell.lblDescription.text = pregunta.nomPregunta
    for start in cell.starts {
        start.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    cell.setStart(position: pregunta.position)

    AnimationsUtil.animationTableCell(cell: cell)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}

@objc private func onClick( _ button: UIButton) {
    position = button.tag
    setStart(position: position)

    let view = button.superview //content view de la celda
    let cell = view?.superview as! EncuestaRespuestaC
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

    preguntas[indexPath.row].respuesta = position
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Por los cambios anteriores el modelo de la celda quedaría así:

```
class EncuestaRespuestaC: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart01: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart02: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart03: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart04: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ivStart05: UIButton!
    private var starts : [UIButton]!
    public var position = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        starts = [ivStart01, ivStart02, ivStart03, ivStart04, ivStart05]
    }

    func setStart(position: Int) {
        for (index, start) in starts.enumerated() {
            let color = index <= position ? Colors.Color.PURPLE_BUTTON : Colors.Color.GRIS_BUTTON
            setColorFilter(button: start, imageName: "ic_star", color: color)
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haberme explicado correctamente y que te ayude para esta ocasión y futuros problemas similares

Comment: Oye muchas gracias me ayudaste demasiado. Quisiera q le heches un ojo a mi comentario de abajo.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo claro tu requerimiento, pero para obtener la Celda seleccionada puedes usar el metodo `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Este respuesta es para Yoana Ugarte García.
Muchas gracias me ayudaste demasiado a entender. 
Mira lo resolví así ya que es el orden de mi UIView.

```
@objc private func onClick(_ button: UIButton) {
        //stackView, view, view, view, cell
        let position = button.tag
        let view = button.superview as! UIStackView
        let cell = view.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview as! EncuestaRespuestaC
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        preguntas[indexPath!.row].respuesta = (position + 1)

        for (index, start) in cell.starts.enumerated() {
            let color = index <= position ? Colors.Color.PURPLE_BUTTON : Colors.Color.GRIS_BUTTON
            setColorFilter(button: start, imageName: "ic_star", color: color)
        }
    }
```

esta es mi jerarquía..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]